# Reduction of an Allylic Enoate to afford allylic alcohol in presence of Benzyl Acetal Groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, organic-reduction

I have a question that requires finding a reagent for the reduction of an enoate to the corresponding allylic alcohol. Preferably done in one step too with an acid workup at the end too.

What types of reducing agents would work?

Would Lithal be too strong and reduce the acetal groups or would it be okay?

[image]

Comment: What is the alkyl group on the ester?

Comment: @Waylander A Methyl group.

Comment: The actual structure of your cmpd. would be handy.

Comment: @user55119 compound is included now, was unsure of how to attach it.

Comment: Thanks for the structure. There may be a stereochemical issue in the lab but not on paper ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your benzyl acetal groups should be stable to all varieties of hydride reducing agents.
For the enoate reduction I suggest Dibal-H or LiBH4/Et2O.

I don't have references for this as I no longer have Scifinder access, and Google is not finding me any references that are not behind paywalls.

Comment: okay thank you very much, LiBH4 was my original thought so I might stick with that. I have included the compound in the original post above if that helps your answer too.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer please accept it, and come back and tell us if the reaction worked.

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be able to carry out the reaction, it was an Organic synthesis lab regarding a 4 step process to produce the above compound before our Christmas break. We have been given further thought-experiments to carry out for our report, such as this one. I very much appreciate the help however.